# `Alert` inside `chrome.storage.sync.get (['auth'] ... ` in `content.js` returns an empty object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

By entering www.app.com I want to access the `auth` key in localstorage and display it in an alert. In the `content.js` file I use`chrome.storage.sync.get`. When I visit www.app.com, an `alert` appears, but its content is just an empty object`{}`, and should contain the content of the`auth` key.

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(['auth'], function(result) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

In localstorage I have key: `auth`,

```
{access_token:"1234567"
  expires_in: 86400
  refresh_token: "8906789"
  scope: null
  token_type: "Bearer"
}
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(['auth'], function(result) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(result));

  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(item, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "EXTENSION",
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [ "*://*.app.com/*"  ],
    "js": [ "content.js" ],
    "all_frames": true
}],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "icon-34.png"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "https://*/",
   "http://*/",
   "*://*.app.com/*",
    "storage"
  ],
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: Check the storage first by running chrome.storage.sync.get('auth', console.log) in devtools console. Also note that HTML5 `localStorage` is not related neither to `chrome.storage.local` nor to `chrome.storage.sync`

Comment: @wOxxOm I put `chrome.storage.sync.get('auth', console.log)` in `content.js`. I click icon extension, next I right-click 'explore', then select 'console'. I go to the tab with the page open, the popup disappears and dev tools along with console.log also disappears and I have no way to check it in the console.

Comment: There's no need to "go to the tab" when you inspect the popup, simply use that devtools window. Also, you can run inspect your content script's context directly in the tab by switching [JS context selector](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/reference#context) in the console toolbar.

Comment: @wOxxOm I can't see anything in console.log. There is no object, undefind etc.

Comment: Sounds like you're not using devtools correctly, https://puu.sh/EGmAF/d8c37188cd.png

Comment: @wOxxOm I have in console.log `undefined`

Comment: So far it sounds like you've customized devtools filters or output. Otherwise it means your browser is broken. Try resetting devtools settings.

Comment: You can also inspect the extension storage using [Storage Area Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb) inside devtools on any extension page.

Comment: @wOxxOm Out of curiosity, I also tried to do something like this: `chrome.storage.sync.set ({foo: 'hello', bar: 'hi'}, function () {
   console.log ('Settings saved');
}); `I can see 'Settings saved' in console.log in the application to which I have access. But in localstorage I don't see `foo: 'hello', bar: 'hi'

Comment: @wOxxOm But if I use its extension in console.log `chrome.storage.sync.get ('foo', console.log);` I can see undefined and {foo: "hello"}

Comment: It just doesn't make any sense which is why I suggest all those things to try. Another one: try `null` instead of `'foo'` to see all values. Also make sure you've read my comments above about localStorage being a totally different unrelated thing. If you want to inspect the values in devtools use the extension I linked above.

Comment: @wOxxOm I did: `chrome.storage.sync.get (null, console.log)`; I have undefined and empty {}

Comment: Ah, now I get it: the storage is empty. You either didn't write the value or some other code cleared it.

Comment: @wOxxOm For example, I'm logged in on stackoverflow. I have access to this page from my extension. In stackoverflow, localstorage has a token. In my chrome extension in `content.js` I should get access to the stackoverflow token in my extension through` chrome.storage.sync.get ('auth', function (result) {
   alert (JSON.stringify (result));
   console.log (JSON.stringify (result));
}); `?

Comment: For the third time, `localStorage` is a different storage.

Comment: @wOxxOm I understand:) I will ask this way: is it possible to access localstorage and token (when I'm logged in on stackoverflow) from my extension in content.js?

Comment: Yes, just access it directly: `console.log(localStorage.auth)`

Comment: @wOxxOm My goal: when I am logged in to stackoverflow, for example, so that the extension automatically detects that I am registered in stackoverflow and logs in automatically when I click the extension icon